# ¿Cómo hacer el filtrado de filas que tengan valor en columnas en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Dado el dataframe
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría filtrar solo los que tengan datos en la columna de Norma Oficial Mexicana, porque además de protección especial hay otros que tienen la característica de amenazado.
Intenté con

`Filtrado <- AICAFLORA %>%  select(Nombre.científico, Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059) %>%  mutate(across(.cols=c(Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059), .fns=factor))%>% filter(Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059=="Amenazada(A)"& Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059=="Sujeta a protección especial (Pr)")`

Pero me devuelve
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para el manejo de strings la librería *stringi* es bastante útil.

```
library (stringi)
```

Recurriendo a esta librería se me ocurre que podrías transformar los campos vacíos en NA de la siguiente manera:

```
AICAFLORA$Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059 <- replace(AICAFLORA$Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059, stri_isempty(AICAFLORA$Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059)==TRUE, NA)
```

Una vez que hayas transformado los campos vacíos en NA, se me ocurren dos posibles maneras en que podrías filtrar en base a mi experiencia.

1. La primera, que es la más parecida a lo que estás intentando, es con la librería *dplyr*:

   ```
    library(dplyr)

    filtrado <- AICAFLORA %>% select(Nombre.científico, Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059) %>% filter(!is.na (AICAFLORA$Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059))
   ```
2. La otra, es recurrir a la librería *sqldf*:

   library(sqldf)

   filtrado <- sqldf ("select* from AICAFLORA where Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059 != 'NA'")

¡Espero que te resulten!

Answer (score 0):

Esto:

```
  filter(Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059=="Amenazada(A)" & 
           Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059=="Sujeta a protección especial (Pr)")
```

Tiene un problema lógico, estás usando el `and` y obviamente la columna no puede tener los dos valores al mismo tiempo, en todo caso usa un `or` ( `|`) para combinar los dos filtros.

Por otro lado, habría que ver que tiene el resto de las celdas, no parece que fueran valores `NA` si simplemente fueran cadenas vacías podría filtrar así:

```
filter(nchar(trimws(Norma.Oficial.Mexicana.NOM.059))>0)
```

Básicamente, eliminamos blancos a derecha e izquierda y filtramos aquellas cadenas que tuvieran 1 o más caracteres.